# Como retornar una consulta de firestore en android Studio

Tags: android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy intentando realizar una consulta a firebase de google, por medio de android studio, en un método externo, pero cuando intento retornar la lista con los datos, me retorna `null`, este es el método que estoy intentando implementar con la consulta.

```
public ArrayList descargar()  {
        DAO dao = new DAO ();
        ArrayList<DAO> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        db.collection("ScoreDictation")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                dao.setEmail(document.getId());
                                dao.setCefr((String) document.get("CEFR"));
                                dao.setGse((String) document.get("gse"));
                                dao.setScore((String) document.get("score"));
                                if (document.get("time") !=null)
                                dao.setTime((Long) document.get("time"));
                                arrayList.add(dao);


                            }

                        } else {
                            Log.d("ScoreDictation", String.valueOf(task.getException()));
                        }
                       
                    }

                });

       return arrayList;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Los *listener* de Firebase son asíncronos. Significa que nada te asegura que el Arraylist esté lleno cuando el método retorne. De hecho, no lo está por eso retorna `null`.

Para resolver tu problema puedes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Declarar el objeto que llenas dentro del listener como un miembro de la clase (así lo tendrás disponible en cualquier contexto).
2. Llamar desde dentro del listener a un método (aquí lo llamaremos `readData()`) donde uses el objeto para aquello que lo necesites. (También puedes pasarlo como parámetro, en cuyo caso no habría necesidad de declararlo como miembro de la clase).

Sería esto básicamente:

```
/*En el cuerpo de la clase*/
private ArrayList<DAO> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public descargar()  {
    DAO dao = new DAO ();
    db.collection("ScoreDictation")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            dao.setEmail(document.getId());
                            dao.setCefr((String) document.get("CEFR"));
                            dao.setGse((String) document.get("gse"));
                            dao.setScore((String) document.get("score"));
                            if (document.get("time") !=null)
                            dao.setTime((Long) document.get("time"));
                            arrayList.add(dao);
                        }
                        /*El método se llamará cuando se haya completado el proceso asíncrono*/
                        readData();

                    } else {
                        Log.d("ScoreDictation", String.valueOf(task.getException()));
                    }
                   
                }

            });

}

public void readData() {
    /*Aquí tendrás disponible el ArrayList y podrás leerlo/usarlo*/
}
```

Esto resolvería tu problema permitiéndote además trabajar de un modo más limpio y organizado.

Aunque te aconsejo que incorpores a la lógica de tu programa un manejo de errores en el que se informe al usuario de la App sobre los fallos. Aquí los estás resolviendo imprimiendo mensajes en el Log, pero el usuario no ve el Log, deberías mostrar en pantalla que el código ha fallado.

También, convendría que vayas pensando en incorporar lo que se conoce como *Componentes de Arquitectura* cuando uses  Firebase. Si te interesa puedes consultar el artículo del blog de Firebase titulado: *Using Android Architecture Components with Firebase Realtime Database* publicado en tres partes: [(parte 1)](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components.html), ([parte 2](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components_20.html)) y ([parte 3](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components_22.html)). Aunque los ejemplos están basados en Realtime Database, lo puedes aplicar también para Firestore. Lo de menos es el código, pues lo fundamental es que allí se explica cómo Firebase trabajaría mejor con Componentes de Arquitectura.